# Tic-Tac-Toe console application (as foundation for Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe)

Tags: c++, game, console, tic-tac-toe, windows

For the purpose of becoming better at C++ programming, I wanted to program [Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tic-tac-toe) as a console application for Windows in C++. However, I thought it would be sensible to create the plain version of Tic-Tac-Toe first. So I made this simple program which I'll later extend/modify for the Ultimate version. I'll have some learning to do, but my goal is to write "*flawless*" code.
I'd like to know how I can improve my code, what some best practices are (that I'm omitting) and last but not least, what I'm already doing well.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

constexpr int cols = 3;
constexpr int rows = 3;
constexpr char cellValueX = 'X';
constexpr char cellValueO = 'O';

/*
Clear console on Windows.
Code used from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6487534/1964817
*/
void clearConsole()
{
    COORD topLeft = {0, 0};
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screen;
    DWORD written;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &screen);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(console, ' ', 
                                screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, 
                                topLeft, &written);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(console, 
                               FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
                               screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, topLeft);
}

class Player
{
private:
    char value;
    bool isAvailable{true};

public:
    Player() {}
    char getValue() { return value; }
    bool operator==(const Player& compareTo) { return value == compareTo.value; }
    void setValue(char newValue)
    {
        if(isAvailable && !(value == cellValueX || value == cellValueO))
        {
            value = newValue;
            isAvailable = false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Can't change value (value already set)." << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

class Grid
{
private:
    class Cell
    {
    private:
        int gridIndexGenerator()
        {
            static int index{0};
            return index++;
        };
        const int id{gridIndexGenerator() + 1};
        char value{static_cast<char>('0' + id)};
        bool isAvailable{true};

    public:
        Cell() {}
        bool getIsAvailable() { return isAvailable; }
        char getValue() { return value; }
        void setValue(char newValue)
        {
            if(isAvailable && !(value == cellValueX || value == cellValueO))
            {
                value = newValue;
                isAvailable = false;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Can't change value (value already set)." << std::endl;
            }
        };
    };
    enum WinDirection
    {
        HORIZONTAL,
        VERTICAL,
        DIAGONAL,
        LAST
    };

public:
    Grid() {}
    Cell cells[rows][cols];
    void display();
    bool checkWin(char playerValue, WinDirection direction);
    bool checkWin(Player player);
};

void Grid::display()
{
    clearConsole();
    for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            const char value{cells[row][col].getValue()};
            std::cout << "[" << value << "]";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
}

bool Grid::checkWin(char playerValue, WinDirection direction)
{
    switch(direction)
    {
        case WinDirection::DIAGONAL:
        {
            return ((cells[0][0].getValue() == playerValue &&
                     cells[1][1].getValue() == playerValue &&
                     cells[2][2].getValue() == playerValue) ||
                     (cells[2][0].getValue() == playerValue &&
                      cells[1][1].getValue() == playerValue &&
                      cells[0][2].getValue() == playerValue));
            break;
        }
        case WinDirection::HORIZONTAL:
        case WinDirection::VERTICAL:
        {
            bool result = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            {
                switch(direction)
                {
                    case WinDirection::HORIZONTAL:
                    {
                        result =
                            (cells[i][0].getValue() == playerValue &&
                             cells[i][1].getValue() == playerValue &&
                             cells[i][2].getValue() == playerValue);
                        break;
                    }
                    case WinDirection::VERTICAL:
                    {
                        result =
                            (cells[0][i].getValue() == playerValue &&
                             cells[1][i].getValue() == playerValue &&
                             cells[2][i].getValue() == playerValue);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(result)
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}

bool Grid::checkWin(Player player)
{
    bool result{false};
    char playerValue{player.getValue()};

    WinDirection direction = static_cast<WinDirection>(0);
    for(int i = 0; i != WinDirection::LAST; direction = static_cast<WinDirection>(++i))
    {
        result = checkWin(playerValue, direction);
        if(result)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game()
    {
        playerX.setValue(cellValueX);
        playerO.setValue(cellValueO);
        player = playerX;
    }
    void play();
    void switchPlayer();
    void getInput();

private:
    Player playerX;
    Player playerO;
    Player player;
    Grid gameGrid;
};

void Game::play()
{
    bool isGameWon = false;
    gameGrid.display();
    for(int i = 0; i < cols * rows && !isGameWon; i++)
    {
        getInput();
        gameGrid.display();
        isGameWon = gameGrid.checkWin(player);

        if(isGameWon)
        {
            std::cout << "Player " << player.getValue() << " won!" << std::endl;
        }
        else { switchPlayer(); }
    }

    if(!isGameWon)
    {
        std::cout << "It's a tie!" << std::endl;
    }
}

void Game::switchPlayer()
{
    if(player == playerX) { player = playerO; }
    else if(player == playerO) { player = playerX; }
}

void Game::getInput()
{
    std::cout << "Your turn, Player " << player.getValue() << "!" << std::endl;

    int inputCell{0};
    int col{-1};
    int row{-1};
    bool badInput{false};
    bool isAvailable{false};

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Select a cell (number, 1 - 9): ";
        std::cin >> inputCell;

        col = (inputCell - 1) % cols;
        row = (inputCell - 1) / cols;

        isAvailable = gameGrid.cells[row][col].getIsAvailable();
        badInput = (!(inputCell >= 1 && inputCell <= 9) || !isAvailable);

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(), '\n');
    }
    while(badInput);

    gameGrid.cells[row][col].setValue(player.getValue());
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.play();
}
```

Comment: @Rakete1111 you're right. Seems to be caused by the last `break;` in the for loop in `checkWin(char playerValue, WinDirection direction)`.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

- You should be attempting to write portable code. I know why you used `windows.h` and don't have an immediate solution but it is something you will want to consider moving forward.
- Class defaults to private so you should not add it to the top of your class. It is however common practice to list public members first so that anyone using your class can read what they have access to without having to read over your private members.
- There are caveats that warn against using `std::endl`. The reasoning for this is that it flushes the stream and can be a performance hit. The counter argument (especially here) is that performance just isnt a concern in a small application. *However* I would further argue that you should try to understand what it is doing. Prefer "\n" especially until you read up on flushing streams.
- You use a boolean switch `isAvailable` and check the values directly to determine if you are accidentally overwriting a players symbol. This is redundant. I would further suggest passing the char via constructor and initializing it and keeping it const. Then no overwriting.
- If you dont want to use the constructor then remove it. The compiler will generate one for you.
- Your enum is not scoped but you treat it as such. See [enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18335861/5416291).
- Your cell should be a struct of it is a private construct of the grid class. It is not logically precarious for the grid to have full access to the Cells inner workings and Grid still encapsulates the cell and can expose only whats needed.
- You once again compare values while maintaining a bool when checking a Cell. Choose one.
- The underlying data structure of your Grid should not be public. In this case `Cell cells[rows][cols];`  You should also consider an std::array<> for added functionslity.
- Your player (read current or active) should be a pointer. Copying here might not be an expensive process but once again you should at least undertand whats happening. You also cant modify the original with your current approach. I believe a raw pointer would be acceptable here as there should be no ownership but merely acting as a reference pointer.

Answer (score 4):

- Organize your code. Separate your Windows API functions from your tic-tac-toe logic with different files. Place class definitions and public free-function prototypes into header files. Leave the implementation details in cpp files.
- Your `Player` class seems unnecessary. The entire functionality of the `Player` class (currently) is just to choose an X or an O. Just use variables instead.
- Your `Cell` class also seems unnecessary. Create a member-function in your `Grid` class that checks if a cell has an X or an O in it.
- The `isAvailable` variable should just be a function that checks if a cell contains an X or an O in it.
- Refactor it to not have global variables. The way you used global variables here is actually pretty good though. All of your globals variables are constants and have internal linking. The `rows` and `cols` variables could easily go into your `Grid` class. You could make them accessible to the `Game` class a variety of ways (public static variables, getters methods, make `Game` a friend class to `Grid`, etc). Similar strategies can be used for `cellValueX` and `cellValueO`. Another thing you could do is put everything into a namespace.
- Your nested switch statements are super ugly. Encapsulate different parts of the logic into separate functions (`checkHorizonals()`, `checkVerticals()`, `checkDiagonals()`, `checkHorizontal(int row)`, `checkVertical(int column)`, etc).
- Iterating through your `enum`s is completely overkill for this problem. If you encapsulate checking your winning conditions into separate functions, you can simplify your logic and make it easier to read. Honestly, you could get rid of the `enum`s altogther.
- Learn about [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). In particular, make sure your member-functions are `const` correct. This allows the compiler to make sure you're not modifying your class when you shouldn't be. It also makes it easy for others to see which functions change the state of an object which functions do not.
- Separate your game logic from your game presentation. Your `Player` and `Grid` classes do error handling by printing out a message to the standard output. Have them return `bool`s or error codes or throw exceptions instead. Keep all of your writing to the console inside the `Game` class. Keep as much of your tic-tac-toe logic in your other classes. This way, if you ever decide to turn this into a game with a UI, all you have to do is replace the logic in `Game`.
- Instead of having your `Grid::display()` function, consider overloading `operator<<`. See the [Stream extraction and insertion section on this site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for details on how to do this.
- Consider your final goal.

  You said you want to create an ultimate tic-tac-toe game. This means you will need to draw tic-tac-toe boards in a 3x3 fashion. Your ultimate tic-tac-toe logic will probably need to call a function that can print out individual rows from each tic-tac-toe board.

  Think about how you will refactor you code for ultimate-tic-tac-toe. I would not recommend changing your `Grid` class to have 81 cells. Instead I would recommend having 10 `Grid` objects (with the final one being the super board).

  You will also probably have to break your game loop into individual turns or steps since you will be switching between game boards almost every turn.